# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I add appsettings.json in order to get connection string but I cannot get my connection string.  Here is my code.

```
public class MovieTheaterDBContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MovieTheaterDBContext>
{
    public MovieTheaterDBContext CreateDbContext(string []Args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        var ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MovieTheaterDBContext");
        //var ConnectionString = "Server=DESKTOPM4\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MovieTheaterManagerment;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MovieTheaterDBContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);

        return new MovieTheaterDBContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }

   
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings":
  {
    "MovieTheaterDBContext": "Server=DESKTOPM4\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=EshopSolution;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

Update: It is my mistake, I have not set this project as startup project .So it can't find appsettings.json.

Comment: Looks like this line `.SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)` or variant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60199695/495455

Comment: Hi @Mistake,please share how do you call `MovieTheaterDBContextFactory` method?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on appsettings.json file and go to the properties and change "Copy to output directory" option to "Copy always"

Answer (score 0):

Check that your appSettings.json file is in the directory where all your projects file are located. Where the .csproj is located.